# Converting String byte [] into Raw byte[] in java

Tags: java, string, arrays

if I have a `byte []` which holds string in this format:

```
abcd 546546545 dfdsfdsfd 5415645
```

and I know the numbers are of type integer. What is the best way to get a raw `byte[]` out of it, wihtout using `String.split()` method?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want this converted because there is lots of ways you might do this?  How is "dfdsfdsfd" an integer? Why don't you want to use split?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It doesn't make much sense as it is. How does a `byte[]` hold a string? What do you mean by a "raw `byte[]`"? How is a `byte[]` supposed to hold an integer value like `546546545`?

Comment: It would make sense if you has a `byte[]` which contain pairs of hexi-decimal which you wanted to convert into a `byte[]` half the length (ignoring spaces)

Comment: I am reading the string from file into a byte array and then I want to convert it into raw byte @TedHopp

Comment: In Java, strings are usually read into a `char[]`. To read them into a `byte[]`, you need to use an encoding. (I suspect you are just using the encoding of the file; if so, you need to let us know what encoding is being used.) I still don't know what you mean by "raw byte". A byte is a byte; what makes a byte "raw"? Do you mean that you want to store the numeric value of each decimal digit in a separate byte? What about the non-digit characters?

Comment: I see. Thanks! The encoding is UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on the following assumptions (none of which are clearly warranted from what you have posted):

- You are currently reading bytes directly out of a file
- The file is stored in your VM's default encoding
- You want to ignore everything that is not a decimal digit
- You want to generate a `byte[]` where each byte contains the numeric value corresponding to the decimal digits found in the file

With these assumptions, I would solve this problem as follows:

```
public byte[] getDigitValues(String file) throws IOException {
    FileReader rdr = new FileReader(file);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        rdr = new BufferedReader(rdr);
        for (char c = rdr.read(); c != -1; c = rdr.read()) {
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                bos.write(c - '0');
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (rdr != null) {
            try { rdr.close(); }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IOException("Could not close file", e);
            }
        }
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

In Java 7, I'd use the [try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
public byte[] getDigitValues(String file) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (Reader rdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        for (. . .
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your answer!